# RSACryptoServiceProvider <-> CryptImportKey Equivalency

Tags: c#, c++, rsa

If I have a key created from a unmanaged app and If I want to import this key in a managed app and generate another key or encrypt it. Basically the same key will be imported/exported back and forth from managed and unmanaged code.

Therefore what is the equivalent to

```
CryptExportKey(hKey, hPublicKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, lpData, &nSize);
```

and

```
CryptImportKey(hProv, lpData, nSize, NULL, 0, &hPublicKey);
```

in the managed world using RSACryptoServiceProvider?

What set of methods in the RSACryptoServiceProvider class are equivalent to the above Crypto APIs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportcspblob.aspx#MtViewDropDownText) and [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, I wrote an article about **RSA** in **C++** and **C#**.
It contains the **code** and all you need to know to have RSA working in both languages, exchanging keys and messages between them :).
I hope it answers all your questions.

You can find it here:
[Crypt in C++ and Decrypt in C# (and C++)](http://riccardotramma.com/2011/02/crypt-in-c-and-decrypt-in-c-and-c/)